# Impossible to put legend along side each bubble in Excel 2007 & 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am drawing a `bubble chart` in `Excel 2010`:

[image]

At the moment, the legends are all situated on the right of the chart. In `Excel 2003`, it is possible to put them along side each bubble, it seems that in `Excel 2010` this option has disappeared.

But I think it is clearer to have legend associated to each bubble, does anyone know how to realize that?

Comment: For future reference this is better suited to Super USer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Legend* is the list of different series in the chart. It is usually on the right side of the chart.

What you want to do is add *Data Labels* to the points on the chart:

- right click your bubbles
- *Add Data Labels*
- right click your data lables, *Format Data Labels*
- check *Series Name*

repeat for each Series

[image]